# Facebook Graph API: how to get a list of all the objects I liked?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

In order to get a list of likes I need to provide an object-id. If I provide my profile I will only get a list of the pages I liked. I currently

```
Graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version="3.0")
profile = graph.get_object('me')
posts = graph.get_connections("me", "likes")
print(len(posts['data']))
```

This currently returns 1, which is correct because I just like 1 page.

But I would like to get a list of all the thousands of likes I placed in specific posts, photos, videos, etc.

I would also like to get a list of all the Events which I didn't create but was invited to.

I can't seem to find a way to do these things. I've gone through the [whole roll of possible things](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) I can gather from my profile and none seems to return what I want. The most promising one was "objects" but I can't seem to get anything out of it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Nuno

Comment: both things are impossible. there is no api for it.

Comment: Thanks what I suspected. Thank you for clarifying.